# Nuxt.js search by query param without reload

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-router

What are the steps needed to make a redirect to search results without page reload in Nuxt.js? So far, it's been sorted this way:

```js
search() {
  location.href = '/search?phrase=' + this.phrase;
},
```

and I need to make it happen without page refresh. In the page's dir is a search directory with index.vue inside like

```
/search/index.vue
```

so far I found some solutions to use $router.on(event) so I have something like this

```js
created() {
  this.$nuxt.$on('pushState', params => {
    history.pushState(
    {},
    null,
    'search?phrase=' + encodeURIComponent(params)
    )
  })
},
beforeDestroy() {
  this.$nuxt.$off('pushState')
},
methods: {
  search() {
    this.$nuxt.$emit('pushState', this.phrase)
  }
},
```

However, all I have managed to achieve is to change the URL, but no redirection is happening. So what are the steps necessary to make this redirection to the mainURL + 'search?phrase=' + query so that user would be indeed redirected, and the items were displayed like right now.

In the /search/index.vue items are fetched and displayed, but how do I force router to go to this URL not only display it in the browser?

Comment: You're probably looking for [router push](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/navigation.html#router-push-location-oncomplete-onabort) here?

Comment: You want the router.push() and maybe you will also want to use https://nuxtjs.org/docs/components-glossary/watchquery/

Comment: thank you the router push kind of works but I am not getting expected behavior, after redirect URL is identical to the one when I use window.location.href, however when I use window location I get results, and when I use router I get page could not be found, and address is 100% identical

Comment: When you were using window.location, you were basically nuking your SPA. If you're moving with `router.push`, you need to handle the data loading. You're doing this part wrong I guess. Could you share us the code that you're using to fetch the data?